# iOS how to change default onPress button color

Tags: ios, button

I have been trying to figure out this problem for a while now and no avail. I have a program I inherited and it uses a a white background image for the buttons. You can change what image you want easily from UI editor. When the user presses down on that button the white background image is switched out for a different image, showing a blue highlight instead. For the life of me I can't find where that is being referenced at. I even tried adding a new button and it is the stock highlight color.

Where is that onPress reference probably at? Or where can I re-reference this new button to have a new onPress image background?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the button in Interface Builder. Open the attributes inspector for that button. Under Button you can choose the "State Config". Change that to "Highlighted". Now you can change the Image config for the highlighted state.